# ffmpeg API: handle frame loss in hevc encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

Everything works fine until the introduction of frame->pts increment due to frame loss.

Below is the regular progression without frame->pts increments:

> frame->pts=8 pkt->pts=512 pkt->dts=-512 pkt->flags=1
> frame->pts=9 pkt->pts=2560 pkt->dts=0 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=10 pkt->pts=1536 pkt->dts=512 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=11 pkt->pts=1024 pkt->dts=1024 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=12 pkt->pts=2048 pkt->dts=1536 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=13 pkt->pts=4608 pkt->dts=2048 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=14 pkt->pts=3584 pkt->dts=2560 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=15 pkt->pts=3072 pkt->dts=3072 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=16 pkt->pts=4096 pkt->dts=3584 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=17 pkt->pts=6656 pkt->dts=4096 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=18 pkt->pts=5632 pkt->dts=4608 pkt->flags=0

When I introduce the frame->pts increment it happens:

> frame->pts=15 pkt->pts=512 pkt->dts=-512 pkt->flags=1
> frame->pts=17 pkt->pts=4608 pkt->dts=2048 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=19 pkt->pts=2560 pkt->dts=1536 pkt->flags=0
> [mp4 @ 0x7eff842222c0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 2048 >= 1536

So I wrote the following code as a "quick" solution (between av_packet_rescale_ts() and av_interleaved_write_frame()):

```
   av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, c->time_base, st->time_base);  
   ...
   if (pkt->dts<=previous_dts)  
     {  
      if (pkt->pts<=previous_pts)  
        {  
         pkt->pts=previous_dts+1+pkt->pts-pkt->dts;  
        }  
       pkt->dts=previous_dts+1;  
     }  
   previous_dts=pkt->dts;  
   previous_pts=pkt->pts;  
   ...
   ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
```

Now I no longer have the error, but the values are:

> frame->pts=15 pkt->pts=512 pkt->dts=-512 pkt->flags=1
> changed frame->pts=15 pkt->pts=512 pkt->dts=1 pkt->flags=1
> frame->pts=17 pkt->pts=4608 pkt->dts=2048 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=19 pkt->pts=2560 pkt->dts=1536 pkt->flags=0
> changed frame->pts=19 pkt->pts=3073 pkt->dts=2049 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=21 pkt->pts=1536 pkt->dts=1536 pkt->flags=0
> changed frame->pts=21 pkt->pts=2050 pkt->dts=2050 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=23 pkt->pts=4096 pkt->dts=3584 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=25 pkt->pts=8704 pkt->dts=6144 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=27 pkt->pts=6656 pkt->dts=5632 pkt->flags=0
> changed frame->pts=27 pkt->pts=7169 pkt->dts=6145 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=29 pkt->pts=5632 pkt->dts=5632 pkt->flags=0
> changed frame->pts=29 pkt->pts=6146 pkt->dts=6146 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=31 pkt->pts=7680 pkt->dts=7168 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=33 pkt->pts=12800 pkt->dts=10240 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=35 pkt->pts=10752 pkt->dts=9728 pkt->flags=0
> changed frame->pts=35 pkt->pts=11265 pkt->dts=10241 pkt->flags=0
> frame->pts=37 pkt->pts=9728 pkt->dts=9728 pkt->flags=0
> changed frame->pts=37 pkt->pts=10242 pkt->dts=10242 pkt->flags=0

What is the correct way to handle frame loss scenario?
Is there a way to inform the encoder about frame loss?

The encoder is "hevc_qsv" and the output format is mov (.mp4).